# Why can't you do basic operations AFTER an aggregate in a window function? Like (max(x)+5), vs (5+max(x))

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, syntax, window-functions

The syntax for aggregates and window functions is confusing, this does not work,

```
SELECT (max(x)+5) OVER ()
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x);
```

While this works

```
SELECT 5+max(x) OVER ()
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x);
```

That's fine if the [operator is commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), but [I'm trying to divide an interval by seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175693/124486) (in my specific case though I worked around it). Is there anyway to simplify this.

```
SELECT (max(x)/5) OVER ()
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x);
```

So another encapsulating query is not needed? Is this a PostgreSQL thing, or a SQL thing? Is there a way to disambiguate the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to divide the result of the window function by 5. The entire window function consists of `MAX(x) OVER ()` therefore your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(x) OVER ()/5 FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x);
```

This will result in 10 rows all containing the value 2, since the generate_series function results in 10 rows and each would contain the result of our window function.

Comment: purely for clarity, it can be useful to write this as `(MAX(x) OVER ())/5`

Comment: or, `div(max() OVER (), 5)`. I just can't believe that's how SQL parses it. That's especially ugly.